# Is there any way to ignore JsonProcessingException without breaking deserialization process

Tags: java, playframework, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm looking into a solution for Jackson deserialization JSON to an instance of a class without breaking the whole process, currently when I do something like:

If Actor.class was like:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonPropertyOrder(alphabetic = true)
public abstract class BaseDTO {

}

public class Character extend BaseDTO {
    private LocalDateTime updatedDate;
    private String name;

    // Setters and getters 
}
```

and deserialize json `{"updatedDate":"N/A", "name": "Jon Snow"}` like:

```
String json = "{\"updatedDate\":\"N/A\", \"name\": \"Jon Snow\"}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final Character character = mapper.reader().forType(Character.class).readValue(json);
```

Or as Play Framework directly:

```
final Character character = Json.fromJson(json, Character.class);
```

I definitely will get an exception like:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String "N/A": Text 'N/A' could not be parsed at index 0
```

And `InvalidFormatException` actually is a `JsonProcessingException`, there is also `MismatchedInputException` and other exceptions, so I need somehow gracefully continue with processing and get the object `character` and have `name` value at least instead of stopping it at all.

I prefer to:

- Use annotations to config the parser or any solution to be applied to `BaseDTO`.
- Logging the issue in the log file so I know that something wrong happened.

I really can't find the way right now without a huge effort, so I wonder if there is any out-of-box solution do that without re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Not sure if i understood question completely, I have 2 suggestions which may help.  1. Add `new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)`  to ignore extra fields in  json not  in pojo. 2. You can add custom deserializers for fields you expect `N/A` etc string.

Comment: @Archit my problem that I get some JSON data from remote service, that service get changes many times, when the service changes the data or structure, I get the whole API to fail (the API that talks to that service), I want to keep that service running with the least issues.

Comment: Interesting, I have usually seen cases where your API payload depends on service data structure, so what you are facing is expected. But if you want to work with varying API payload, consider accepting a JsonNode or Map, it then needs to be handled appropriately.

Comment: @Archit I read data using web service, I have wrapper between the structure I get from API and the one that I return to the frontend, so this is why I do this, the problem is mainly the date format that sometimes using non standard format, sometimes it is like DDMMYYYY sometimes ISO sometimes with time and so on.

Comment: perhaps then you can do custom parsing as in my example below. DateTimeFormatter provides ways to parse optional fields.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you wannt ot consider string like `N/A` as null. Using a custom deserializer it can be achieved like this.

```
class LocalDateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {
    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        if ("N/A".equals(p.getText())) return null;
        return LocalDateTime.from(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.parse(p.getText()));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!